Are Dividends part of operating earnings?
Berkshire Hathaway owns shares in many public traded companies and those shares pay a cash dividend. Recently Berkshire Hathaway reported earnings. The earnings report can be found at the following URL:
Earnings Report
It is my claim that the dividends that Berkshire Hathaway received are not part of its operating earnings. Am I right about that?

It depends on the nature of the business.

Probably better to ask the accounting q&a rather than personal finance.

@PeteB. except there is no accounting Q&A...

@DStanley odd, there used to be!

There was a beta site at one point but it was taken down (not enough usage I suppose?)

It presumably depends on whether the investments are actually part of the business model...

Most of the stock owned by Berkshire Hathaway is owned by the insurance subsidiaries. As such, the dividends from that stock is included on the "Insurance-investment income" line. And that line is, indeed, included in Operating Earnings.

Yes, since the investments are part of their business model, but with a few caveats -
When companies pay a dividend, their share price goes down the same amount (for reasons that are described on many other answers on this site). So the dividend "gain" is offset by an unrealized loss in the investment, so the immediate effect on investment income/loss is zero. In fact, you can read their fairly comprehensive warnings about the accuracy of "investment gains' in any one quarter due to accounting rules.
Note that there might be some non-operating investments that BH makes that also pay dividends, which would not be in "Operating Income", but I do not see any detail in their earnings release or financial report that would give any more detail.
